How to access Azure SQL server using MSI in Azure DevOps pipeline?
I have a Azure SQL server with a database. Azure SQL server has a Managed Service Identity. I want to insert some records into the database via a Azure Devops pipeline.
What are the steps to be followed?

Hi! Would need a bit more here in terms of context - are you using Microosft-managed agents or your own? What are the authentication requirements for your Azure SQL server? How is the firewall configured? Basically Azure DevOps is not in any sense more special than anything else that would need to access Azure SQL - you need network access, you need authentication. This may help with the network side: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents

We have a private pool of agents, we can whitelist the route from Agent pool to SQL server. Main purpose is to automate insertion of few records into a database. This will happen frequently. We do not want to build a front end just for insertion of some records. We will create UAMI and provide Contributor access to SQL DB


How to access Azure SQL server using MSI in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can use the Pipeline task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 - Azure SQL Database deployment v1 task.
Here are the steps:
Step1: You can use the Managed Service Identity to create an Azure Resource Manger Service Connection in Project Settings -> Service Connections -> Find Azure Resource Manager -> Managed identity
For example:

Step2: You can use the Managed Service Identity ARM service connection in the Azure SQL Database deployment task to connect to the Azure SQL Database.
At the same time, you also need to fill in the fields such as sql authentication method and sql script/file/dacpac file to complete the deployment.
For example:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Execute Azure SQL : DacpacTask
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
    ServerName: '<Database server name>'
    DatabaseName: '<Database name>'
    SqlUsername: '<SQL user name>'
    SqlPassword: '<SQL user password>'
    deployType: SqlTask
    SqlFile: sqlfile

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Azure SQL database deployment
